# Closed form expression of odd series

Tags: summation, closed-form

Does there exist a closed-form expression for the series below?

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-rx}}{\ln(r+1)}$$

I’m pretty sure this series converges for $x \geq 0$, though I haven’t checked myself. Even so, I’m not sure that there’s even an expression for this. Just wondering if there was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\;z:=e^{-x}\,$ for $\,x>0\,$ (i.e. $\;z<1$) then you want :
$$S_z:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{\ln(k+1)}$$
Since $\;\displaystyle \frac 1{\ln(k+1)}=\int_0^\infty (k+1)^{-s} ds\ \;$ for $k>0\;$ we may rewrite $S_z$ as :
$$S_z:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k+1)^s}\,ds$$
I'll let you prove that $\sum$ and $\int$ may be exchanged to get :
\begin{align}
S_z&=\frac 1z\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k+1}}{(k+1)^s}\,ds\\
&=\frac 1{z}\int_0^\infty\operatorname{Li_s}(z)-z\;ds\\
\end{align}
with $\operatorname{Li_s}$ the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) ([evaluation using alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28polylog%28s,1%2F2%29-1%2F2,s%3D0..infinity%29)).

Of course this doesn't help much for a closed form. Integrating polylogarithms relatively to their first parameter (denominator's power) is not easier than integrating zeta functions but it could define a new (possibly interesting) special function.
Analytic continuation may be used too to evaluate your series for any value of $z\neq 1$.

Comment: Holy I didn’t see that coming. Nice super awesome thanks for this beautiful answer.

Comment: On a side note can’t this already be considered an analytic continuation already? Seeing that I could sub x as any value not equal to zero, doesn’t this already extend it to the rest of the complex values?

Comment: Glad you liked this answer @Horus and yes for $|z|>1$ we may use the $\;\operatorname{Li}_s(z)/z-1\;$ integral for the analytic continuation even if the definition of $\,S_z\,$ and the series defining the polylogarithm $\;\displaystyle  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k^s}\;$ are divergent. Excellent *continuation*,

Comment: That’s another upvote for me haha

Answer (score 1):

It's rather unlikely to have a closed form.  For $x > 0$, it does converge: just use the comparison test with a geometric series.  For $x=0$, it does not converge.

Comment: Wouldn’t it also converge for $x=0$ too since using the integral test gives it a finite value?

Comment: No. $\int_1^\infty \frac{dr}{\ln(r+1)}$ diverges.

Comment: Wait no sorry I remembered the integral wrong. Yes it doesn’t converge at zero.

Comment: It does converge at 0, but not at infinity.

Comment: Seriously? Based on integral test for convergence it should diverge at 0 but converge to zero at infinity no? @user

Comment: @Horus Sorry. I meant the function $1/\log x $, not  $1/\log(1+ x) $. The integral of the latter of course diverge both at 0 and at infinity.